# cannot find -lSDL_image

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm trying to learn SDL and I've added the following:

C:\SDL2_image-2.0.4\i686-w64-mingw32\include\SDL2

C:\SDL2_image-2.0.4\i686-w64-mingw32\lib

to my linker/compiler search directories and:

-lSDL_image

to linker settings, but my code is returning the error: "cannot find -lSDL_image".

The code is as follows:

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>

(...)
```

in Game.h and

`#include "Game.h"`

in both main.cpp and Game.cpp respectively. All .dlls are in place, so I'm unable to eliminate what might be causing the error.

Comment: Seem to be the naming of the lib is different? I'm seeing libSDL2_image.a inside the lib folder so should it be -llibSDL2_image instead? Sorry I don't have MinGW setup to test this (using VS2017) - adding this as comment per Jesper Juhl suggestion (still new with Stackoverflow.)

Comment: Solution works, thanks!